# How to configure Vue mapActions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

vue-cli store

my code like this:
 ...mapActions('some/nested/module',[
      'getCountry',
      'getCurrency'
    ]),

[image]

How to set up mapActions path in the Vue component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mapActions` is used in a component's `methods` property.

```
// my-component.vue
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('namespaced/module', [
            'myAction',
            'myOtherAction'
        ])
    }
}
```

The namespace can determined by the module's filename. For example, given a file - `moduleA.js` - getters, mutations, actions would be namespaced as `moduleA/someGetter`, `moduleA/someAction`, `moduleA/someMutation`.

```
...mapActions('moduleA', [
    'someAction',
    'anotherAction'
])
```

> When the module is registered, all of its getters, actions and mutations will be automatically namespaced based on the path the module is registered at

The other way is using the `registerModule` method, which allows for dynamic runtime registration:

```
// register a module `myModule`
store.registerModule('myModule', {
  // ...
})

// register a nested module `nested/myModule`
store.registerModule(['nested', 'myModule'], {
  // ...
})
```

[Vuex Docs - Namespacing](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#namespacing)

[Vuex Docs - Dynamic Module Registration](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration)

Comment: how to set namespace?   export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        account: {
            namespaced: true,
            modules: {
                user,
                set
            }
        }
    }

})  ；