# How can I reference vuex 'constant' named actions with variables?

Tags: javascript, constants, vuex

I have an action in my vuex store like this:

```
 [FETCH_ADAM_BROWN_LIST](state)({commit}) {
     /* Action logic */
 },
```

I want to access similarly name actions, e.g. FETCH_CHRIS_MATHISON_LIST using a variable like so:

```
this.$store.dispatch(`FETCH_${this.person}_LIST`);
```

However this throws an error:

```
VM90646:37 [vuex] unknown action type: FETCH_ADAM_BROWN_LIST
```

But it will work when I specify it a constant:

```
this.$store.dispatch(FETCH_ADAM_BROWN_LIST);
```

***How can I access 'constant' named actions with variables?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try using mapActions? That could work for what you want. Helpful link: [How to configure Vue mapActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548718/how-to-configure-vue-mapactions)

Answer (score 0):

I use this structure in my Vuex Store. Many of mine actions are dispatched using a concatenated string as argument. But my actions are declared like this:

```
setCurrentUser: function ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }, userDB) {
  commit('setCurrentUser', userDB)
  dispatch('resetDashboards', userDB.dashboards)
}
```

Then, I can dispatch like this:

```
let type = 'User'
this.$store.dispatch('setCurrent' + type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there something strange in your code. Remove the `(state)`, cause **actions** receive a `context` object which in your case, you are destructuring in the params. `({commit})`.

Set like this and let me know if this works.

```
[FETCH_ADAM_BROWN_LIST]({commit}) {
     /* Action logic */
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, when you passed `FETCH_${this.person}_LIST` to `dispatch`, the action type that was dispatched is the concatenated constant name and not the actual value of the constant variable.

To get the actual value of the your constant variable, you can use the [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> The argument of the `eval()` function is a `string`. If the string
>   represents an expression, eval() evaluates the expression.

You can use it like this:

```js
const FETCH_ADAM_BROWN_LIST = 'customAction';

const person = 'ADAM_BROWN';
const actionToDispatch = `FETCH_${person}_LIST`;

console.log(eval(actionToDispatch)); // customAction
```

*Be careful with using `eval` though. If you're absolutely sure your input is sanitized before passing it along, then it shouldn't be a problem.*